# How to prevent draw() from resetting transformations in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Is there any way by which I can prevent `draw()` from resetting all transformations every time it resets? I am trying to simulate the growth of an L-system and want to achieve something like this:
[Barnsley Fern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fractal_Farn.gif)

In order to achieve this I need to keep track of all the transformations and rotations within the `draw` function in order to show the growth effect. Using a user-defined function instead of draw just draws the final tree and does not show the tree being "drawn"

So my question is basically this:
**Is there any way I can prevent `draw()` from resetting all transformations?**
or
**Any way I can keep track of the x, y coordinates and angle of the canvas** so that every time draw resets, I can translate back to the previous state using the stored coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [push()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and [pop()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop):

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  //some initializations

  push(); //save an initial drawing state
}

function draw() {
  pop(); //restore latest saved drawing state (including transformations)

  // do some stuff

  push(); //save current drawing state (including transformations)
}
```

Comment: @AyushNandi Your welcome :) And please don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it solves the issue.